# How to add a whole section using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

So I am trying to write a script to add a whole, newly added, section to Adobe Analytics. I am not sure I can do it though, so I will appreciate your help. I thought I should add a class name to the section and use document.getElementsbyClassName but it does not seem to work? I also need to add the nested divs and their styles again using JS?
Here is my code:

```html
<section class="flex-columns" style="
    background-color: crimson;
    height: 450px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
"> 
   <div style="
    top: 132px;
    left: 340px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
">
    <p style="
    top: 187px;
    left: 391px;
    width: 31px;
    height: 138px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 120px/36px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
">1</p>
    <p style="
    top: 326px;
    left: 391px;
    width: 298px;
    height: 152px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 45px/50px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #888888;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 30px;
">Find your nearest store</p>
</div>
    <div style="
    top: 132px;
    left: 340px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
"> 
<p style="
    top: 187px;
    left: 811px;
    width: 66px;
    height: 138px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 120px/36px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-left: 30px;
">2</p>
<p style="
    top: 326px;
    left: 811px;
    width: 298px;
    height: 152px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 45px/50px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #888888;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 30px;
">Book a free hearing test</p>
</div>
    <div style="
    top: 132px;
    left: 340px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
">
    <p style="
    top: 187px;
    left: 1231px;
    width: 68px;
    height: 138px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 120px/36px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: black;
    border: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-left: 30px;
">3</p>
    <p style="
    top: 326px;
    left: 1231px;
    width: 298px;
    height: 152px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 45px/50px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #888888;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 30px;
    /* margin-bottom: 0px; */
">Get supported by our experts</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any JS code. Also, what does this have to do with Adobe Analytics? It's just HTML so far.

Comment: I need to write a code in JS which takes the HTML and CSS and uploads it to the page/analytics. I thought it should be 'document.getElementsbyClassName="flex-columns"....but I am not sure this is the right way

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please be more clear about what exactly you want. What is the end result of your goal?  Are you trying to see that html content show up in Adobe Analytics reports? Adobe Analytics tracks user activity on your website.  It has nothing to do with the content of your website itself. Nor should you be uploading html content to Adobe Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Since the post editing queue is full, I am sharing the current work in this area again. Could you explain the problem more clearly?

```js
/* I don't understand what the problem is and what you want to do! */
```

```css
.section-style {
    background-color: crimson;
    height: 450px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Common */
.columns {
    top: 132px;
    left: 340px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.titles{
    top: 187px;
    height: 138px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 120px/36px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: black;
}

.contents{
    top: 326px;
    width: 298px;
    height: 152px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 45px/50px Value;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #888888;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

/* Titles */
.title-first {
    left: 391px;
    width: 31px;
    opacity: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

.title-second {
    left: 811px;
    width: 66px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.title-thirth {
    left: 1231px;
    width: 68px;
    border: 2px;
    border-color: black;
}

/* Contents */
.content-first {
    left: 391px;
    height: 152px;
}

.content-second {
    left: 811px;
}

.content-thirth {
    left: 1231px;
    /* margin-bottom: 0px; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="flex-columns section-style">
        <div class="columns">
            <p class="titles title-first">1</p>
            <p class="contents content-first">Find your nearest store</p>
        </div>

        <div class="columns">
            <p class="titles title-second">2</p>
            <p class="contents content-second">Book a free hearing test</p>
        </div>

        <div class="columns">
            <p class="titles title-thirth">3</p>
            <p class="contents content-thirth">Get supported by our experts</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```